# how to pass data from one Tableview to another Tableview when button is pressed in cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, segue

Im trying to pass data from the ViewController to my CartViewController. The cells in the ViewController have 3 buttons(optionBtns) that have a price and weight label above each of them.

What Im trying to do is have the optionBtn selected pass the label data above it once the ATC button is pressed

the ATC button in the cell passes the data of image, name, category, and optionBtn data to the CartViewController cells(CartCell)

how would I be able to pass selected data to the CartVC when the ATC is pressed to present selected item Name, Image, and Category in cell with selected optionBtn data(Price & Weight)

I am also using Cloud Firestore to post data to populate my VC cells

[image]

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var items: Items!    
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var category: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var weightOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightThree: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var priceOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceThree: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var addToCart: RoundButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var optionBtn1: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionBtn2: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionBtn3: RoundButton!

    var addActionHandler: (() -> Void)?

    func configure(withItems items: Items) {
        name.text = items.name
        category.text = items.category
        image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: items.image))
        priceOne.text = items.price1
        priceTwo.text = items.price2
        priceThree.text = items.price3
        weightOne.text = items.weight1
        weightTwo.text = items.weight2
        weightThree.text = items.weight3
        self.items = items
    }

    var lastSelectedButton = UIButton()
    @IBAction func cartTypeSelected(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        lastSelectedButton.isSelected = false; do {
            self.lastSelectedButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        lastSelectedButton = sender 
        sender.isSelected = true; do {
            self.lastSelectedButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGreen
        }
    }
    @IBAction func atcBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.addActionHandler?()
    }   
}
```

---

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController {

    var items: Items!
    @IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        cartTableView.dataSource = self
        cartTableView.delegate = self
    }

}

extension CartViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Cart.currentCart.cartItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell", for: indexPath) as! CartCell

        let cart = Tray.currentCart.cartItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(withItems: cart)

        return cell
    }
}
```

---

```
class CartCell: UITableViewCell {

    var selctedBtn: Cell?

    @IBOutlet weak var lblMealName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageUrl: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblSubTotal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblWeight: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func configure(withItems items: Items) {
        // lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight1)"
        lblMealName.text = "\(items.category): \(items.name)"
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        // lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price1)!)"
        imageUrl.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: items.imageUrl))

        if selctedBtn?.optionBtn1.isSelected == true {
            lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price1)!)"
            lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight1)"            

        } else if selctedBtn?.optionBtn2.isSelected == true {
            lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price2)!)"
            lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight2)"

        } else if selctedBtn?.optionBtn3.isSelected == true {
            lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price3)!)"
            lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight3)"

        }
    }  
}
```

---

```
class Cart {
    static let currentCart = Cart()
    var cartItems = [Items]()
}
```

Comment: In `ViewController`, when you call `cell.configure(withItem: itemSetup[indexPath.row])`, didn't you forget about setting cell's delegate? `cell.delegate = self`. Because I don't see any place where you do it.

Comment: I forgot to add it in when I edited it last, but it is there now, and has been there in my code

Comment: just updated my code, I think im a lot closer to the solution, just dont know where to go from there, if you wouldn't mind taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the values in closures.

So, in your Cell class you could change your closure var to:

```
 var addActionHandler: ((Int) -> Void)?
```

Then, in your addToCart button action, something along these lines:

```
@IBAction func atcBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // pass back the user selected values
    var i = 0
    switch lastSelectedButton {
    case optionBtn1:
        i = 1
    case optionBtn2:
    i = 2
    default:
        i = 3
    }
    self.addActionHandler?(i)

}
```

Create a .selectedOption property of your Items class, you should add one (of type Int). You can use that to track the user's selection.

Modify cellForAt in Cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? Cell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    // use var to make item mutable
        var item = itemSetup[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(withItem: item)
        cell.addActionHandler = { (option: Int) in
        print("Option selected = \(option)")
        item.selectedOption = option

        Cart.currentCart.items.append(item)
    }

    return cell
}
```

In your CartCell you can make the labels like this:

```
    if items.selectedOption == 1 {
        lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price1)!)"
        lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight1)"            

    } else if items.selectedOption == 2 {
        lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price2)!)"
        lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight2)"

    } else if items.selectedOption == 3 {
        lblSubTotal.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: items.price3)!)"
        lblWeight.text = "\(items.weight3)"

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If the idea is for firebase to handle all of your data then the data should go through firebase and not through the viewController. ie your Firebase db should have an `items` collection (or perhaps one per `store`) and your `user` should have a `cart` collection.  When the use taps the add to cart button you add the item in question to that users cart collection in firebase then show the cartViewController.  The cartViewController should subscribe to the `cart` collection on the current user and then populate its tableview from that firebase collection.

TLDR the typical design of a firebase app is that the firebase DB is the source of truth for the app, so you should write all changes to firebase and then simply observe these collections elsewhere in the app.  This also insures that if the user edits the cart on another device that it will update itself on the iOS device with the new cart items.

Comment: **@Josh** that's a great idea whi h would make things work better for me when things are set up, but im not trying to do that yet im simply trying to pass data to the CartVC after the ATC btn is pressed in the cell along with the option selected data as well. ive been stu k trying to make this work for when I press an option button and the ATC btn that it sends data to the CartVC cell of the selected cell.

Comment: I just Updated my code to where it now passes data from the VC to the CartVC but how would I be able to make it pass the data for the selected optionBtn (Weight & Price) to pass that selected data to the CartVC